# How to get large number in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to get epochtime (13 digits) after subtracting from `task_end_time` column using something like

```
((task_end_time - to_date ('01 Jan 1970 00:00:00', 'DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 3600* 1000)::bigint AS "log_datetime"
```

This gives me below exception

```
ERROR: XX000: Integer data overflow (multiplication)
```

[image]

Comment: try to convert to bigint before multiplication, converting at the end doesn't help because it's simply switching data type, while you need to switch data type before multiplication is done to overcome integer constraints... also, probably you need to get epoch using native function that's available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like all you actually need to do is

`extract('epoch' from task_end_time) AS "log_datetime"`